# Using dplyr::if_else with purrr

Tags: r

I am trying to use `purrr::map_dbl` on a list where I want different behavior if the list element is `NULL`.

```
x <- list(NULL, c(1, 2), c(3, 4))
purrr::map_dbl(x, function(y) { dplyr::if_else(is.null(y), 0, y[1] + y[2]) })
```

This does not work as expected, instead giving the error:

> Error: `false` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 0

Debugging the `if_else` call, I see that `y[1] + y[2]` is evaluated to `integer(0)`. Why doesn't this work?

The following all work as I would expect:

```
> purrr::map_dbl(x, function(y) { dplyr::if_else(is.null(y), 0, y[1]) })
[1] 0 1 3
> purrr::map_dbl(x, function(y) { dplyr::if_else(is.null(y), 0, y[2]) })
[1] 0 2 4
> purrr::map_dbl(x, ~ dplyr::if_else(is.null(.x), 0, .x[1]))
[1] 0 1 3
> purrr::map_dbl(x, function(y) { base::ifelse(is.null(y), 0, y[1] + y[2]) })
[1] 0 3 7
> purrr::map_dbl(x, function(y) { if (is.null(y)) 0 else y[1] + y[2] })
[1] 0 3 7
```

What is different about the original call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can debug, it easily with `browser()`

```
purrr::map_dbl(x, function(y) {
        browser()
        dplyr::if_else(is.null(y), 0, y[1] + y[2]) 
 })
Called from: .f(.x[[i]], ...)
Browse[1]> 
debug at #1: dplyr::if_else(is.null(y), 0, y[1] + y[2])
Browse[2]> 
Error: `false` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 0
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

So, here the `length` is the issue.

According to`?if_else`, requires all arguments to have the same length

> Values to use for TRUE and FALSE values of condition. They must be either the same length as condition, or length 1. They must also be the same type: if_else() checks that they have the same type and same class. All other attributes are taken from true.

---

To dig further into the issue, it still works if the value is not `NULL`

```
v1 <- 1
if_else(v1==1, 0, v1[1] + v1[2])
#[1] 0
```

But, as soon as we change it to `NA` or `NULL`, it becomes an issue, could be due to the `type`

@CBraun made an interesting observation

```
NULL[1] + NULL[2]
#integer(0)
```

returns length 0,

```
if_else(is.na(v1), 0, integer(0))
```

> Error: `false` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 0
>       Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

However,

NA + NA
   #[1] NA

is of `length` 1, but still returns error

```
v1 <- NA
if_else(is.na(v1), 0, v1[1] + v1[2])
```

> Error: `false` must be a double vector, not an integer vector
>       Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

If we use the correct `NA` dispatched, it works

```
v1 <- NA_real_
if_else(is.na(v1), 0, v1[1] + v1[2])
#[1] 0
```

Notice that here it is the `type` issue.  All in all, as mentioned in the documentation, `length` and `type` should match for `if_else`

Bottomline: When the value is `NULL`, the behavior is strange because of the output of `+` is `integer(0)` of length 0

---

It is a case where we can use `if/else` instead of `if_else`

```
purrr::map_dbl(x, ~ if(is.null(.x)) 0 else sum(.x))
#[1] 0 3 7
```

---

In that respect, use the `sum` instead of calling the arguments separately `y[[1]]`, `y[[2]]` as this cause imbalance in the length

```
purrr::map_dbl(x, ~ ifelse(is.null(.x), 0, sum(.x)))
#[1] 0 3 7
```

Note that `ifelse` also requires the lengths to be same, though it works here due to recycling of values

> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as test and data values from the values of yes or no.

```
purrr::map_dbl(x, ~ ifelse(is.null(.x), 0, .x[[1]] + .x[[2]]))
#[1] 0 3 7
```

NOTE: All the methods are used to check the OP's condition.  But, if the objective is to get the result, there are other ways.

Comment: *Why* is length the issue though? That is, why is `if_else` seeing `false` as length zero? Also, I'd like to generalize this for other functions than sum (for example `runif(1, .x[1], .x[2])`.

Comment: @C.Braun  The `length` is an issue because `if_else` requires the length to be the same.  I have quoted the documentation line where it specifically says it wants length to be the same.  If you look at the `condition` argument, it is a vector of length 1 for first list element, then the true condition is length 1, while the false condition output get the length to 1, but it is still checking for [[1]] and [[2]]

Comment: I think @C.Braun 's question is not so much "why `if_else` needs the length to be the same", but "why does `if_else` think `.x[1] + .x[2]` is zero length, as shown in the error

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Yes the point I was missing was that the `false` gets evaluated regardless of what `condition` evaluates to. The error was confusing to me as it was evaluating `NULL[1] + NULL[2]` which gives `integer(0)` (because any indexing of `NULL` returns `NULL` and the `+` function is fine with that).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the `na.rm` argument in `sum` to ignore `NA` or `NULL` values when adding values together. This way we can skip the if else logic:

```
purrr::map_dbl(x, sum, na.rm = TRUE) 
# [1] 0 3 7
```

Here is the Base R equivalent (as pointed out by akrun):

```
sapply(x, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to generalize this for other functions like `runif(1, .x[1], .x[2])`?

Comment: @C.Braun How is `runif` gonna fit into this? is `.x[1]` and `.x[2]` supposed to be the min and max for the uniform distribution?

Comment: Exactly. Suppose `x` were a vector of min/max distribution values, and I wanted the result to be a random sample within that range.

Comment: @C.Braun And what should a vector with `NULL` return in this case? In order to "generalize", these are the rules that need to be laid out. Every function takes in different arguments.

Comment: By generalize I mean I'd like the `if_else` to return some scalar if the list element is `NULL`, and to be able to use `.x[1]` and `.x[2]` as the inputs to *any* function that takes 2 numeric arguments.

Comment: The question is less about a specific use case and more about understanding why my `if_else` construction is invalid.

Comment: @C.Braun and I'm saying you can't with `runif`, because it takes three arguments, `n`, `min` and `max`. I don't think you can generalize this to _any_ function without providing the function. Unless the function itself would be a parameter to be passed in. This also looks like two questions you're asking: 1. why is my `if_else` construction invalid. 2. How to create a function that takes a list of vectors as arguments to another function. I suggest you open a new question to address the latter.

Comment: agreed about the second question. I am still interested in knowing why `if_else` is interpreting my false value as length zero though.

Comment: @C.Braun I'm not entirely sure, but I suspect it's because when `map_dbl` gets to `NULL`, `.x[2]` does not exist, so `.x[1] + .x[2]` returns a zero length vector. Your function works if you change your list to `x <- list(c(1, 2), c(1, 2), c(3, 4))`. `if_else` checks the length of `TRUE` and `FALSE` _before_ it evaluates the `is.null` condition, so your attempt to return a zero when `is.null` is true doesn't really work